# Apps for car safety?

Tags: android, windows-phone, car

I have recently brought a car which I'm forced to keep it outside, away from my direct look for most of the time and am really concerned for it being getting stolen.

I am looking for an app which would help me in preventing car theft.

What I am looking for:

I have two mobile devices - one running Android and other running Windows. I want an app that I can install on one the device and leave it in the car with GPS enabled.

As soon as the car moves, it should send alert to the other device that I have with me. Is there such an app?

Comment: They sell GPS units that can be hidden in the car and will text you when it detects movement.  There's a remote so you arm it when you leave.  If your car is gone you can text it and it will reply with GPS coordinates.  Best of all a decent one is only $50 and then $10 a month for cell service.  It's permanently wired so you don't need to worry about batteries.

Comment: Thanks Zach. This sounds like an easy permanent solution.Can you please point me to any such service sites - It would be great.In the meantime, let me explore some nearby car accessory stores.

Comment: Try [Mileage vehicle GPS Tracker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nomanprojects.mycartracks) app, and see [this](http://www.mycartracks.com/learn-how-to-create-a-fleet) to know how to workaround for your case (_note: AFAIK,this app doesn't support windows_)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is certainly a collection of apps you can use for this. One of the keywords to check is [Geo-Fencing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geo-fence) here, available with a bunch of e.g. "child protection" apps (see: [Location Monitoring](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/childprotect#group_461)): you define the area your "child" (here: car) is permitted to be in, and as soon as it leaves that area (your car moves) an alert is triggered. Examples here are [GPS or Network Tracking](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tplanet) (not too many permissions requested; alerts per SMS) or [tinyTraker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.innovita.tinytraker).

Alternatively, whenever something shall be automated, I always think of *Tasker* – which of course also can deal with GeoFences, and can send alerts in many ways – e.g. per SMS or mail. *Tasker* doesn't come entirely for free (though there's a 7-day trial available on its website), but it can do a lot of things, so you might at least wish to check. For that, I recommend taking a look at my [collection of Tasker resources](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/resources_tasker).

I must admit I have no experiences in this area (Geofencing), so I cannot tell you how well the mentioned Android apps work. But the first two are free, so you can at least try them out – and *Tasker* is known to be "***the*** non-plus-ultra automation app on Android".

Comment: Thanks Izzy.This definitely served as my starting point.I could figure out an app - [life360](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.life360.android.safetymapd) which serves my purpose.I am yet to figure out how to set up a geo-fence.But it serves my purpose.

Comment: Glad to read – thanks for your feedback! And good luck with the app :)

Answer (score 2):

You can probably come up with a recipe for [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/), (If This Then That), which will detect motion on one phone and send a text to the other, if there isn't one already.

Comment: Thanks Steve for the suggestion.I tried creating a recipe but the accuracy is not so great.I mean, it asks me to select a large enough area as a 'geo-fence'.

Comment: @Soumya - I think that you are trying to create a recipe based on GPS coordinates you could try for one using the phones acceleration detectors - must try to look into that.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen a device/solution on kickstarter:
https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/416260479/smartwallit-redefines-wallet-and-makes-wallet-smar/description

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to try [**Matrix Internet Tracking**](https://www.matrix.co.za/tracking-services/smartphone-tracking)

With Matrix Smartphone Tracking, you can track your vehicle or those of your loved-ones on selected Smartphone devices - anywhere, anytime; in real time!
***All Android and iPhone users who have either the Matrix [MX2](https://www.matrix.co.za/tracking-devices/detail/mx2) or [MX3](https://www.matrix.co.za/tracking-devices/detail/mx3) fitted to their vehicles*** can use this Smartphone Tracking Service to view:

- your vehicle's movement history
- individual trip routes on the map
- the start and end point of each trip
- your vehicle's current location
- the current speed of a moving vehicle
- your position in relation to that of your vehicle